# php mysql update limit

Tags: php, insert-update

I want to update mysql database, where `directory = 0`, and just update `5 of records` which value `0` to `art`.

for explain:

```
id    |   directory
1     |   fashion
2     |   0    //update here into 'art'
3     |   travel
4     |   fashion
5     |   0    //update here into 'art'
6     |   0    //update here into 'art'
7     |   travel
8     |   0    //update here into 'art'
9     |   0    //update here into 'art'
10    |   0    //this is 6th record, do not update, leave the value as '0'.
11    |   fashion
```

Is this update code right? thanks.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE articles SET directory = 'art' WHERE directory ='0' LIMIT 5");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your [syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) is fine.

i will add an order by clause (to be sure)

```
ORDER BY `Id`
```

to query

```
UPDATE articles SET directory = 'art' WHERE directory ='0' ORDER BY id LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query doesn't seem wrong to me.

But note that you might also want to specify an `order by` clause, to be sure which are the five "first" items :

```
update articles
set directory = 'art'
where directory = '0'
order by id
limit 5
```

Just as a reference : [UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)