# SQL UPDATE query fails with LIMIT 1 but works with LIMIT 2

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, sql-update

I have a strange problem with a query in my php script.

I have a table with many thousand rows that ALL match the queries below, so I (wanted to) use LIMIT 1 to only update one of them.

When I ran these queries in my script and via phpMyAdmin:

Query 1 returns '1 rows affected':

```
UPDATE licenses SET license_refunded = 'no'
WHERE license_status = 'available'
ORDER BY license_id ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Query 2 returns '0 rows affected':

```
UPDATE licenses SET license_refunded = 'no'
WHERE license_status = 'available'
AND license_years='1'
ORDER BY license_id ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Query 3 returns '2 rows affected':

```
UPDATE licenses SET license_refunded = 'no'
WHERE license_status = 'available'
AND license_years='1'
ORDER BY license_id ASC
LIMIT 2;
```

As you can see, the only difference between Query 1 and Query 2 is the "AND license_years='1'", and the only difference between Query 2 and Query 3 is the LIMIT 1 and LIMIT 2.

Can anyone shed some light on this, why is Query 2 not affecting 1 row?

Query 2 does update 1 row (as it should) when being run via a mysql client (Linux terminal).

Is this a php/mysql bug?

Comment: why your are using `LIMIT`? is your table `id` Auto-Increment?

Comment: I don't see why the LIMIT would cause an issue but it is strange to use a LIMIT in an update.  If your update affects more than 1 row and it isn't supposed to then you need to look at modifying your query or table structure.

Comment: The query would update many thousand rows without LIMIT. I want it to update only the first one matching the WHERE clause. What puzzles me more is that if I only use 1 clause in WHERE  (without " AND  license_years='1' "), it works with LIMIT 1.

Comment: Try an ORDER BY as stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528885/php-mysql-update-limit

Comment: but you would never know which that is..it could be random

Comment: @blckbird there is no problem with it picking a row at random, as long as only one row is affected.

Comment: @valicu2000 UPDATE licenses SET license_refunded = 'no' WHERE license_status = 'available' AND license_years =1 ORDER BY license_id ASC LIMIT 1; also return 0 rows affected.

Comment: Don't you have a `Warnings: 1` note after `0 row affected`? If yes do `SHOW WARNINGS` to see what happens...

Comment: @ring0 no, doing the query in phpmyadmin I get a green checkmark saying 0 rows affected when doing LIMIT 1, and a green checkmark saying 2 rows affected when doing LIMIT 2.

Comment: Can you try with a *mysql* client?

Comment: @ring0 ok, this is strange... it works when doing it via terminal mysql: mysql> UPDATE licenses SET license_refunded = 'no' WHERE license_status = 'available' AND license_years = 1 ORDER BY license_id ASC LIMIT 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0  .... why is this not working in phpmyadmin or in my php script, while running it with LIMIT 2 works?!

Comment: Well I guess PHPmyAdmin does a transaction and *rollback* if something does not go as planned - now what is "ok" and "not ok" according to PMA must be found reading the source code. This is why I don't use PMA for specific/important tasks. Sometimes these high level tools are "too smart"!

Comment: @ring0 It also doesn't work in my php script... that is why I started testing the query in phpmyadmin in the first place. Could this be some kind of bug? The query seems to be OK, at least when judging by what the mysql client returned.

Comment: UPDATE licenses SET license_refunded = 'no'
WHERE license_status = 'available'
AND license_years='1' AND  license_refunded <> 'no'
LIMIT 1;

Comment: @ggiroux that query does not work in the mysql client, my php script, or phpmyadmin using LIMIT 1 or LIMIT 2. Doesn't <> mean "everything BUT" ?

Comment: I have modified my question to more clearly show the problem, and also added an ORDER BY. The 2nd query with LIMIT 1 is still affecting 0 rows. I am more or less convinced this is a bug when having "AND" in the WHERE clause together with "LIMIT 1", but not even sure where to report it... anyone?

Answer (score 0):

This works how for me just how you expected

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c69f0/1/0

Comment: Thanks, I will use that site to test when in doubt in the future. The query also works when being run in a mysql client, it just doesn't work when being run via php... I tried 2 different php versions and 2 different SQL server version (local development and production server). I have a feeling this is a PHP bug...